# Forge API error: Duplicate entry for key "forge_buildevent_config_hash_uniq"

Tags: trigger.io

We get the following error from the Forge API from time to time.

```
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.88
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[   INFO] Running from build-tools
[   INFO] Using generate_dynamic.buildtools for build
[  ERROR] Forge API call to reload/buildevent/create went wrong: Internal error: (1062, "Duplicate entry '4ba544af411281f9ee4f74bcf373ca7bf1e02051' for key 'forge_buildevent_config_hash_uniq'")
[ FAILED]Error: Command failed: [   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.88
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[   INFO] Running from build-tools
[   INFO] Using generate_dynamic.buildtools for build
[  ERROR] Forge API call to reload/buildevent/create went wrong: Internal error: (1062, "Duplicate entry '4ba544af411281f9ee4f74bcf373ca7bf1e02051' for key 'forge_buildevent_config_hash_uniq'")
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Observing the same when doing multiple builds at once. Is there some kind of limitation to only do 1 build at a time?